# The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, properties, parallel-processing

I am using the following code.

```
public partial class SettingApp
{
    public SettingApp()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Parallel.Invoke(SetDataInTextBox);
    }

    private void SetDataInTextBox()
    {
        txtIncAns.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.IncludeAN;
        txtIncAuthor.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.IncludeAutt;
        txtIncQuo.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.IncludeQU;
        txtIncSpBegin.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.IncludeSP;
    }
}
```

The program gives the following error

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>
> thread owns it.

Which is the right way

**update :**

Whether this is right :

```
   public partial class SettingApp
{
    private delegate void SetDataInTextBoxDelegate();
    public SettingApp()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        txtIncAns.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new SetDataInTextBoxDelegate(SetDataInTextBox));
    }

     private void SetDataInTextBox()
    {
        txtIncAns.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.IncludeAN;
        txtIncAuthor.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.IncludeAutt;
        txtIncQuo.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.IncludeQU;
        txtIncSpBegin.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.IncludeSP;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now that you have removed the `Parallel.Invoke` call, does it simply all run on the UI thread?  If so, you don't need to call `Invoke` on the control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the UI thread can access UI elements, which I'm guessing is what those `txt` things are.  `Parallel.Invoke` is in your case not the UI thread, so the exception is thrown when you try to access the `.Text` property on the controls.

You need to marshal the call across to the UI thread.  In WinForms, controls have various ways to help you do this:

```
if (myControl.InvokeRequired)
{
    myControl.Invoke(...);
}
else
{
    myControl.Text = "something";
}
```

MSDN has an article with examples on it here (VS2010):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/757y83z4(v=VS.100).aspx

**Update 1:**

For WPF the model is similar, but includes the Dispatcher:

```
myControl.Dispatcher.Invoke(...);
```

- [MSDN Forum Post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/wpf/thread/f4f1242b-f75d-4708-a952-ef667b90c9a7)
- [MSDN Article](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx)

**Update 2:** Of course, it looks like you don't even need to use multi-threaded code here.  I would guess the overhead of using the multi-threaded portion is more than the code you eventually call.  Simply remove the use of multiple threads from this section and set the properties directly:

```
    public SettingApp()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetDataInTextBox();
    }

    private void SetDataInTextBox()
    {
        txtIncAns.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.IncludeAN;
        txtIncAuthor.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.IncludeAutt;
        txtIncQuo.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.IncludeQU;
        txtIncSpBegin.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.IncludeSP;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As Adam said, only the UI thread can access UI elements. In the case of WPF, you'd use `myControl.Dispatcher.Invoke()`.

Since these calls are all going to be invoked on the UI thread anyway, you should remove the `Parallel.Invoke()` and call the method directly.

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternate suggestion.  I would move toward databinding your textboxes to properties of a class, even if you don't want to go the full MVVM design, databinding is your friend in WPF.  Then if you need the threading, WPF will handle updating controls on UI thread when the property changes, even when the property is changed on another thread.